# Why does my if is not executing

Tags: java, mysql, resultset

```
ResultSet rs;
System.out.println("rs");
try 
{
    rs = j.getData("select ulevel from user where ulevel='"+eid+"'");
    System.out.println("try");
    //until this point it works properly. But after this point it doesn't work as I thought even though I logged in as a user whose user level (ulevel) is not admin.
    if(rs.next())
    {
       System.out.println("rs.next");
       if(rs.getString(2).equals("Admin"))
       {
          System.out.println("if admin");
          home.setEnabled(true);
          job.setEnabled(true);
          employee.setEnabled(true);
          user.setEnabled(true);
          machine.setEnabled(true);
          branch.setEnabled(true);
      }
        else if(rs.getString(2).equals("user"))
        {
            System.out.println("else if");
            home.setEnabled(true);
            machine.setEnabled(true);
            System.out.println("user can't see");
        }
        else
        {
             System.out.println("else");
        }
    }
} 
catch (Exception ex) 
{
    Logger.getLogger(Home_Page.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

}

---

From above code I tried to limit the number of pages that can be seen by a normal user whose user level (ulevel) is user. I tried

```
jbutton_name.setvisible(false);       
jbutton_name.setEnabled(false)
```

as well.But both of them are not effective for disabling those buttons for a normal user.
Could anybody please help me??? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't throw or catch `Exception`. Look up "SQL injection attack".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the 2 in `rs.getString(2)` is the result column index (starting from 1 for the first column)

But as you are only getting one column back from the query

```
select ulevel from user
```

it will not work

As per [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getString(int))

> SQLException - if the columnIndex is not valid; if a database access
>   error occurs or this method is called on a closed result set

Also I suggest that you use a [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) and `setString` to avoid concatenation for your SQL generation to avoid the possibility of SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Thank you very much again...I'll try those.. :)

Comment: Finally could find out why this if doesn't work. Value of rs.next()=false. That's why.

Answer (score 1):

I think query didn't return a result. If it did then **rs.getString(2)** should throw an exception.

Comment: Thank you. You put me in the correct direction. :) My rs.next()'s value is false. now struggling to make it true. :)

Comment: I am new here. Can you please tell me whether it is ok if I clicked the upper arrow appearing next to your reply? (I did so)

Comment: there must be a right symbol below the down arrow , you can click that. if you cant find it then then its ok :-)

Comment: Just did that. :)